# Spyder not working after installation of other packages

Tags: qt, pyqt, anaconda, spyder

In summary: as far as I recall, after conda-installing fenics and sfepy (along with, through pip, some dependencies), I cannot run spyder:

$ spyder

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charles/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 6, in 
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "/home/charles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/charles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in 
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/charles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in 
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by /home/charles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWebKitWidgets.so)

Along the method of
https://www.scivision.co/fix-spyder-cxxabi-not-found-qt-error/

Would it be a terrible idea to simply copy

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5

to

~/anaconda3/lib/

a la

cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 ~/anaconda3/lib/

?

I'm paranoid about breaking something, is there a high probability of that happening?

Surely there's a better way to do this, no?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using conda-forge packages?

Comment: Thanks Carlos, yes, most (if not all) of the packages (along with qt) from conda forge were installed as fenics/sfepy dependencies

Comment: A couple of things: you **shouldn't** mix conda-forge and default packages because they are binary incompatible. Besides, the Qt5 conda-forge package was broken on Linux, which is causing the error you're seeing. That's being fixed right now, so if you do `conda update pyqt` in two or three hours, this problem should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, both for your swift response, and for bringing this excellent IDE to us!